# Is it possible to publish and consume VS extensions from Azure DevOps package management?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I would like to publish my VS extension like we publish the NuGet packages - to the Azure DevOps Package Management on every CI build.
But then, developers need to download and run it manually, because VS does not recognize it as a valid source of VS extensions.

Is it possible to configure VS so that it looks for packages somewhere else, in addition to the extension market place? Azure DevOps Package Management is ideal, but a shared directory on the company Intranet would work too.

Comment: There's an open request for this over at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/791130/add-support-for-visual-studio-extension-feeds-in-a.html
Please go there and vote to get this prioritized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure VS so that it looks for packages somewhere
>   else, in addition to the extension market place?

For VS2017 and VS2019, we can share the extension by posting it to [Private Gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/private-galleries?view=vs-2019).

But for now, the host should be an `Atom Feed` or `SharePoint site`, it **doesn't support** `Azure Devops Package Management`(feeds in Artifacts?) or `Shared Directory`.

**In addition:**

Since the extension can't be installed in a running VS instance(It needs us to close VS instance to complete the installation), so actually we don't need to use the search option in `Extensions and Updates` within VS IDE if we're just trying to share the extension in the company.

Use a shared directory on the company Intranet, place the extensions(.vsix) in that, and members in same company Intranet can install that by double-click the xx.vsix file. (The function of auto-updating extension in VS is not available for this situation, but it meets the needs in most of the time. )

Comment: Is there any extension for Azure DevOps that introduces an Atom feed which can be used to publish VS extensions?

Comment: Sadly, so far I haven't found that kind of extensions [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Installs):-(